# Unable to sequentially process a file > 250kb using Windows file mapping with n-sized chunks

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to make a software that takes a txt file and xor every 4 byte with a pre-defined number.
I am doing this mapping the file in memory and opening chunks of the file with MapViewOfFile of size n.
The algorithm I'm attaching works well for txt files of less than 250 kb. But for file > 250kb it only xor some parts of the file and I cannot understand why and how to fix this.
Can someone help me?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned int strToUl(char *s)
{
    int size = 4;
    unsigned int ul = 0;
    memcpy(&ul, (unsigned int *)s, size);
    return ul;
}

char *ulToStr(unsigned int *ul)
{
    int size = 4;
    char *tch = (char *)calloc(size, sizeof(char *));
    memcpy(tch, (char *)ul, size);
    return tch;
}

unsigned int uixor(unsigned int n, unsigned int seed)
{
    srand(seed);
    unsigned int mask = rand();
    char ch[5] = { 0 };
    strcpy_s(ch, 5, ulToStr(&n));
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        ch[j] = ch[j] ^ mask;
    }
    return strToUl(ch);
}

BOOL mapWriteChunk(PHANDLE phFile, DWORD dwFileSize, int start, int buffsize, uint32_t xork)
{
    DWORD offset = start;// / 4;// / sizeof(DWORD);
    SYSTEM_INFO SysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&SysInfo);
    DWORD dwSysGran = SysInfo.dwAllocationGranularity;
    DWORD dwFileMapStart = (offset/dwSysGran) * dwSysGran;
    DWORD dwMapViewSize = (offset % dwSysGran) + buffsize;
    DWORD dwFileMapSize = offset + buffsize;

    unsigned int *ulMVBuffer = (unsigned int *)MapViewOfFile(*phFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, dwFileMapStart, 0);
    if (ulMVBuffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("ulMVBuffer = NULL\n");
    }

    int iViewDelta = offset - dwFileMapStart;

    for (int i = 0; i < buffsize; i++)
    {
        unsigned int *u = (unsigned int *)ulMVBuffer + (iViewDelta + i);
        unsigned int u1 = *u;
        unsigned int u2 = uixor(u1, xork);
        *u = u2;
        printf("write on %d -> ", iViewDelta);
    }

    UnmapViewOfFile(ulMVBuffer);

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    char name[] = "test.txt";

    OFSTRUCT tOfStrIn;
    tOfStrIn.cBytes = sizeof tOfStrIn;
    HANDLE hFile = (HANDLE)OpenFile(name, &tOfStrIn, OF_READWRITE);
    DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);

    HANDLE hFileMap = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, dwFileSize, NULL);
    if (hFileMap == NULL)
    {
        printf("hFileMap = NULL\n");
    }


    int pos = 0;
    int chunk = 4;
    int bSize = dwFileSize / sizeof(DWORD);
    int rseed = 10;

    for (pos = 0; pos < bSize; pos+=chunk)
    {
        mapWriteChunk(&hFileMap, dwFileSize, pos, chunk, rseed);
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    CloseHandle(hFileMap);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: code is terrible. you really want map/unmap section after every 4 bytes ?! map by allocation granularity. for what you pass in only parameter `hFileMap` to `mapWriteChunk` by pointer ?! and you can close file handle just after create section on it

Comment: @RbMm Code is terrible because this is experimenting code. I'm trying to figure out how it works.
You can change the chunk size with the appropiate variable.
I'm using granularity, as you can see inside "mapWriteChunk" and I'm using the pointer to hFileMap to create MapViewOfFile sections and I'm closing it when I finish using it. As far as I understood, MVOF should be created on chunks of a big file, to read it. If you have a better solution, can you provide me some corrections (possibly with code)? I posted the question to have a solution, actually...

Comment: you must use chunk multiple `dwAllocationGranularity` you need call `GetSystemInfo` once. you not need pass pointer to `&hFileMap` but value `hFileMap` - *I'm closing it when I finish using it* - and so what ?! for what here need pointer ?

Comment: and use `dwFileSize` in call `CreateFileMapping` you also must not. pass 0 here

Comment: All those suggestions don't fix the problem, though.  
The only way in which it works is if I create the MapViewOfFile using char * instead of unsigned int *.  
Do you know how to make it work with unsigned int *? I need to xor 4 byte at a time with the mask (4 characters).

Comment: Also, using char *, it works also with chunks of 4 (any size, actually).

Comment: simply your program logic is invalid. all this not related to winapi, memory-mapped-files, etc

Comment: @RbMm can you tell me what in my program logic is invalid? Looks to me that you don't know much about memory mapping... you're suggesting things that MSDN don't. I took most of the code from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: ok, if you even can not use ready correct code, i delete it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem and I'm writing here so anyone who have the same problem, know what's wrong.
Talk is cheap, I show you the code (and then I'll explain):

```
char *ulMVBuffer = (char *)MapViewOfFile(phFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, dwFileMapStart, 0);
if (ulMVBuffer == NULL)
{
    printf("ulMVBuffer = NULL\n");
}

int iViewDelta = offset - dwFileMapStart;

unsigned int mask = myrand(xork);
for(int i = 0; i < buffsize; i++)
{
    unsigned int c = ulMVBuffer[iViewDelta + i] ^ mask;
    ulMVBuffer[iViewDelta + i] = c;
}
```

So you have to map the memory using a char pointer and then, when you use the XOR operator like  that:

```
unsigned int c = ulMVBuffer[iViewDelta + i] ^ mask;
```

You obtain the XOR to be applied to a group of 4 bytes and  not only on 1 byte, because - as far as I understood playing around - the XOR between a char (1 byte) and a unsigned int (4 bytes) forces the operator to pick 3 more bytes from the memory and use it for the bitwise operation.
This wasn't working using a pointer to unsigned int because, I guess, it stored the bytes from the memory in a different fashion (maybe OS or machine dependent?) and so you were able to XOR only 1 byte every 4 and not groups of 4 bytes all together.

If anyone has a better understanding to this or wants to add more to this solution, I will be more than happy to read it!

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​You did the right thing: self-answer if you have a solution.